# error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant. No idea what this means

Tags: c, arduino

I got this errror code while working with an arduino. The code is ment to take in text and output an LED in morse code. It currenltly doesn't have the text input function. Thanks!

```
    void setup() {
      // put your setup code here, to run once:

    }

    void a(){
     digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(1000);    
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(1000);        
     digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(3000);  
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(3000);   
    }
    void b(){
      digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(3000);  
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
     delay(1000);
     digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(1000);    
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(1000); 
      digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(1000);    
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(1000); 
      digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(1000);    
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(3000); 
    }

    void c(){
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(3000);  
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
     delay(1000);
      digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(1000);    
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(1000);  
      digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(3000);  
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
     delay(1000);
     digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(1000);    
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(3000);  
    }
    void d(){
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(3000);  
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
     delay(1000);
     digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(1000);    
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(1000); 
      digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(1000);    
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(3000); 
    }
    void e(){
       digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(1000);    
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(3000);  
    }
    void f (){
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(1000);    
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(1000);    
      digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(1000);    
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(1000);    
      digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(3000);  
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
     delay(1000);
     digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(1000);    
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(3000);   
    }
    void g (){
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(3000);  
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
     delay(1000);
     digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(3000);  
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
     delay(1000);
     digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(1000);    
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(3000); 
    }
    void h (){
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(1000);    
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(1000);     
      digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(1000);    
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(1000);     
      digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(1000);    
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(1000);     
      digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(1000);    
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(3000);     

    }
    void i (){
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(1000);    
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(1000);     
      digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(1000);    
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(3000);     
    }
    void j (){
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(1000);    
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(1000);     
      digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(3000);  
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
     delay(1000);
     digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(3000);  
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
     delay(1000);
     digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(3000);  
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
     delay(3000);

    }
    void k (){
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(3000);  
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
     delay(1000);
      digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(1000);    
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(1000);  
     digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(3000);  
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
     delay(3000);

    }
    void l (){
     digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(1000);    
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(1000);  
      digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(3000);  
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
     delay(1000);
       digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(1000);    
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(1000);  
       digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(1000);    
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(3000);  
    }
    void m (){
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(3000);  
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
     delay(1000);
     digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(3000);  
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
     delay(3000);
    }
    void n (){
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(3000);  
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
     delay(1000);
     digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(1000);    
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(3000);  
    }
    void o (){
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(3000);  
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
     delay(1000);
     digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(3000);  
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
     delay(1000);
     digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(3000);  
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
     delay(3000);
    }
    void p (){
     digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(1000);    
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(1000);        
      digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(3000);  
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
     delay(1000);
     digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(3000);  
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
     delay(1000);
     digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(1000);    
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(3000);  
    }
    void q (){
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(3000);  
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
     delay(1000);
     digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(3000);  
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
     delay(1000);
     digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(1000);    
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(1000); 
        digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(3000);  
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
     delay(3000);
    }
    void r (){
     digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(1000);    
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(1000);  
      digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(3000);  
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
     delay(1000);
       digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(1000);    
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(3000);  
    }
    void s (){
     digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(1000);    
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(1000);  
       digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(1000);    
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(1000);  
       digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(1000);    
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(3000);  
    }
    void t (){
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(3000);  
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
     delay(1000);
    }
    void u (){
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(1000);    
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(1000); 
      digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(1000);    
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(1000); 
      digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(3000);  
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
     delay(3000);
    }
    void v (){
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(1000);    
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(1000); 
      digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(1000);    
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(1000); 
      digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(1000);    
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(1000); 
      digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(3000);  
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
     delay(3000);
    }
    void w (){
     digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(1000);    
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(1000);  
      digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(3000);  
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
     delay(1000);
     digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(3000);  
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
     delay(3000);
    }
    void x (){
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(3000);  
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
     delay(1000);
     digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(1000);    
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(1000);   
      digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(1000);    
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(1000); 
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(3000);  
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
     delay(3000);  
    }
    void y (){
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(3000);  
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
     delay(1000);
     digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(1000);    
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(1000);   
      digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(3000);  
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
     delay(1000);
     digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(3000);  
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
     delay(3000);
    }
    void z (){
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(3000);  
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
     delay(1000);
     digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(3000);  
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
     delay(1000);
      digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(1000);    
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(1000);   
       digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(1000);    
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(3000);   

    }
    void 1 (){
     digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(1000);    
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(1000); 
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(3000);  
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
     delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(3000);  
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
     delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(3000);  
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
     delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(3000);  
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
     delay(3000); 
    }
    void 2 (){
     digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(1000);    
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(1000);   
       digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(1000);    
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(1000); 
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(3000);  
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
     delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(3000);  
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
     delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(3000);  
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
     delay(3000);

    }
    void 3 (){
     digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(1000);    
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(1000);   
       digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(1000);    
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(1000);   
       digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(1000);    
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(1000);   
      digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(3000);  
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
     delay(1000);
     digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(3000);  
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
     delay(3000);
    }
    void 4 (){
     digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(1000);    
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(1000);   
       digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(1000);    
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(1000);   
       digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(1000);    
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(1000);   
       digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(1000);    
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(1000);   
      digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(3000);  
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
     delay(3000);
    }
```

void 5 is number 5 so when someone types in 9, it will blink morse for 5

```
void 5 (){
     digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(1000);    
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(1000);   
       digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(1000);    
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(1000);   
       digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(1000);    
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(1000);   
       digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(1000);    
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(1000);   
       digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(1000);    
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(3000);   
    }
    void 6 (){
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(3000);  
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
     delay(1000);digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(1000);    
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(1000);  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(1000);    
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(1000);  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(1000);    
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(1000);  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(1000);    
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(3000);  
    }
    void 7 (){
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(3000);  
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
     delay(1000);digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(3000);  
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
     delay(1000);
     digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(1000);    
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(1000);  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(1000);    
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(1000);  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(1000);    
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(3000);  
    }
    void 8 (){
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(3000);  
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
     delay(1000);digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(3000);  
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
     delay(1000);digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(3000);  
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
     delay(1000);
     digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(1000);    
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(1000);  
      digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(1000);    
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(3000);
```

void 9 is number 9 so when someone types in 9, it will blink morse for 9

```
    }
    void 9 (){
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(3000);  
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
     delay(1000);digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(3000);  
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
     delay(1000);digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(3000);  
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
     delay(1000);digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(3000);  
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
     delay(1000);
     digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(1000);    
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(3000);  
    }
    void 0 (){
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(3000);  
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
     delay(1000);digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(3000);  
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
     delay(1000);digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(3000);  
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
     delay(1000);digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(3000);  
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
     delay(1000);digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(3000);  
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
     delay(1000);
    }


    void loop() {
      // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
     //put enter text code here:

    }
```

Thanks you!

Here are all the errors:

```
MorseBusyWork.ino:29:6: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
MorseBusyWork.ino:30:6: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
MorseBusyWork.ino:31:6: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
MorseBusyWork.ino:32:6: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
MorseBusyWork.ino:33:6: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
MorseBusyWork.ino:34:6: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
MorseBusyWork.ino:35:6: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
MorseBusyWork.ino:36:6: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
MorseBusyWork.ino:37:6: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
MorseBusyWork.ino:38:6: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
MorseBusyWork.ino:391:6: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
MorseBusyWork.ino:413:6: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
MorseBusyWork.ino:436:6: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
MorseBusyWork.ino:458:6: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
MorseBusyWork.ino:480:6: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
MorseBusyWork.ino:502:6: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
MorseBusyWork.ino:520:6: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
MorseBusyWork.ino:539:6: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
MorseBusyWork.ino:559:6: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
MorseBusyWork.ino:578:6: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
Error compiling.
```

MorseBusyWork is the name of the file...

Comment: sorry for the strange formatting with the quotes.

Comment: Why are copy-pasting your own code so many times?

Comment: Alejandro the code takes text input and flashes an LED in morse code. I know i could have just used a library or something else but the class i am in told us to do it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a function named as a numeric constant, change your functions' names to `one(); two(); three();` or better yet create a function that takes an `int` that would be the number of times to blink and use a loop instead of copy-pasting your own code exponentially.

Comment: i know that copy and pasting it was not the most efficient way but the class i am in told me to do it this way. I am trying to figure out what is causing the errors not how to improve my code at the moment. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @MatthewGilbert sounds horrible that a teacher is actually recommending this, the compiling errors are because of what I pointed out, try changing the functions' names.

Answer (score 0):

You should use at least 1 alphabetic letter in yours functions:

```
void number1(){
    // ...
}
```

Comment: check this out: http://www.ele.uri.edu/courses/ele205/ELE205Lab/ELE205_Lab_files/Arduino%20-%20Reference.pdf